# Superclass (or) class definition of Java Primitive?

Tags: java

If Object is superclass of everything, then why does it treat primitives different? Is there any class that is predefined for int, float...(data types)? What is the superclass or where is the class definition for primitives?

Comment: Primitive is not an class, it is a data type, where as Object is a class and every class you create in Java extends it.

Comment: Primitive types are not Objects. All `Object`s are subclass of `Object`.

Answer (score 5):

There is no class definition for Java primitives. There are, however, convenience classes that act as sort of wrappers around primitives, e.g. `Integer` and `Double`. But even these derive from `Object`

Answer (score 3):

Java is an object oriented Language every thing is an object

```
the simple file treated as an object java.io.File
and address of a system as an object java.util.URL
Image can be treated as an Object java.awt.image
every thing is an object in java BUT
The wrapper class are used to convert any data type in to an object.

SO REMEMBER THAT 
the primitive data type is not an object and they do not belong to any class 
Primitive data type are define in the language itself.
you can see the Wrapper class hierarchy
```

Please see the hierarchy of wrapper class.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think you are confused, there are two kinds of variables in Java: reference types and primitive types. Reference types are references to objects. [Primitive Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) contains value.

So if you want to use the `Integer` class to use `int` data type as an unsigned integer. Similarly The `Long class` also contains methods like compareUnsigned, divideUnsigned etc to support arithmetic operations for unsigned long.

So the conclusion is Java primitives have no class, and primitive types are not objects.

Comment: How does the `java.lang.Integer` class relate to unsigned integers? That and `int` are signed, `char` is unsigned.

Comment: my real confusion is how could compiler know what to do after it sees code like int .what is the difference if it see code like Integer instead?